# Odometry isn't reasonable for rotational motion

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, odometry, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The thing is; following screenshot is from simulation, on Gazebo.  (And Real robot does this too.) `ekf_localization_node` uses both of imu and odometry. And using only odometry causes this problem too.

I'm following this guide to tune my robot : [ROS Wiki Navigation Tuning Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) I've set `Decay Time` to `30` and started inplace rotation.

Here is Rviz screenshot:
[image: Rviz]

Odometry isn't reasonable for rotational motion.

Robot's translational motion is good and reasonable. But the rotational motion is bad for localization. What can I do for correcting odometry data? Or Are there any new issues on ekf_localization?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226058/odometry-isn%27t-reasonable-for-rotational-motion/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2016-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, The problem was `wheel_width` parameter in the urdf. It was `0.05` and It caused two contacts under wheel:
[image: image description]

I've set to `0.001` and problem solved, now odometry looks pretty good.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for a real robot, I would say what causes this is a wrong wheel size and wheels distance (assuming a diff drive robot), but as the same happens in simulation, I am not sure about the reason.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1